# SQLite: ROWID not found

Tags: java, android, xml, database, sqlite

I am getting an error whenever i query for data to insert into another activity.

The major problem is that i am not getting an output in my stack trace and being a new programer, i am unable to figure out what is happening.

I am new to SQLite and do not fully understand how the queries work, so any help would be appreciated.

The problem occurs when ever i want to click on an item in the `Listview` on the `activity_main` layout.

I have set the `onItemClickListener` to change the activity to the `edit_data` layout and to fill the `EditText` fields with the appropriate data from the SQLite database table whenever an item on the list is clicked.

But whenever i click on an item it makes a toast that says: "No ID associated with that name".

This toast message is built in to the app by myself, so i know what is toasting this message but i dont know why.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.TheAbstractLightbulb.cohen.not_at_homes_app;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    DBHelper dbHelper;

    public MainActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);


        populateListView();
    }

    public void toInputScreen(View view) {
        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputPage.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in list view.");
        final Cursor data = dbHelper.getData();
        ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            listData.add(data.getString(2));
        }
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MainListView);
        final ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String map = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                String date = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                String notAtHomes = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + notAtHomes);

                Cursor data = dbHelper.getItemID(map, name, date, notAtHomes);
                int itemID = -1;
                while (data.moveToNext()) {
                    itemID = data.getInt(0);
                }
                if (itemID > -1) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                    Intent editDataIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditData.class);
                    editDataIntent.putExtra("id", itemID);
                    editDataIntent.putExtra("map", map);
                    editDataIntent.putExtra("name", name);
                    editDataIntent.putExtra("date", date);
                    editDataIntent.putExtra("notAtHomes", notAtHomes);
                    startActivity(editDataIntent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No ID associated with that name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

EditData.java

```
package com.TheAbstractLightbulb.cohen.not_at_homes_app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * Created by cohen on 2/06/2017.
 */

public class EditData extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "EditData";

    DBHelper dbhelper;

    private int selectedID;
    private String selectedMap;
    private String selectedName;
    private String selectedDate;
    private String selectedNotAtHomes;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_data);
        final Button saveButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton2);
        Button deleteButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteButton1);
        final EditText textNotAtHomes2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textNotAtHomes2);
        final EditText mapNoDisplay2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mapNoDisplay2);
        final EditText dateDisplay2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay2);
        final EditText ListName2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ListName2);
        DBHelper DB = new DBHelper(this);

        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
        // ID
        selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1);
        // Map no
        selectedMap = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("map");
        // Name
        selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");
        // Date
        selectedDate = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("date");
        // Not at homes note file
        selectedNotAtHomes = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("notAtHomes");

        ListName2.setText(selectedName);
        mapNoDisplay2.setText(selectedMap);
        dateDisplay2.setText(selectedDate);
        textNotAtHomes2.setText(selectedNotAtHomes);

        saveButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String item1 = ListName2.getText().toString();
                String item2 = mapNoDisplay2.getText().toString();
                String item3 = dateDisplay2.getText().toString();
                String item4 = textNotAtHomes2.getText().toString();
                if (!item1.equals("")){
                    if (!item2.equals("")){
                        if (!item3.equals("")) {
                            if (!item4.equals("")) {
                                dbhelper.updateData(selectedID, item2, selectedMap, item1, selectedName, item3, selectedDate, item4, selectedNotAtHomes);
                            } else {
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext())
                                        .setTitle("emptyBoxes")
                                        .setMessage("Some boxes have been left empty, /n" +
                                                "are you sure you are done?")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                                        .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                            }
                                        }).create().show();
                            }

                        }

                        }
                    }

                }
            });

        deleteButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbhelper.deleteData(selectedID, selectedMap, selectedName, selectedDate, selectedNotAtHomes);
                Intent intent = new Intent(EditData.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Note Deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        }

        private void toSendNote(View view){
            Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
            sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(EditData.this, SendRecord.class);
                    intent1.putExtra("Note", selectedNotAtHomes);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

DBHelper.java

```
package com.TheAbstractLightbulb.cohen.not_at_homes_app;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by cohen on 31/05/2017.
 */

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "App_database.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "App_date_table";
    public static final String MAP_NO = "Map_no";
    public static final String LOCATION = "Location";
    public static final String DATE = "Date";
    public static final String NOTATHOMES = "Not_at_homes";
    public static final String ID = "ID";
    public static final String TAG = "DBHelper";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + MAP_NO + " INTEGER, " + LOCATION + " TEXT, " + DATE + " INTEGER, " + NOTATHOMES + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertData(String Map_no, String Location, String Date, String Not_at_homes) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MAP_NO, Map_no);
        contentValues.put(LOCATION, Location);
        contentValues.put(DATE, Date);
        contentValues.put(NOTATHOMES, Not_at_homes);

        Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + Location + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }


    }

    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getItemID(String map, String location, String date, String notAtHomes) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + ID + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + MAP_NO + " = '" + map + "' AND " + LOCATION + " = '" + location +
                "' AND " + DATE + " = '" + date + "' AND "
                + NOTATHOMES + " = '" + notAtHomes + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    public void updateData(int id,String newMapNo, String oldMapNo, String newLocation, String oldLocation, String newDate, String oldDate, String newNotAtHomes, String oldNotAtHomes){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + MAP_NO +
                " = '" + newMapNo + " WHERE " + ID + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + MAP_NO + " = '" + oldMapNo + "'"+ LOCATION +
                " = '" + newLocation + " WHERE " + ID + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + LOCATION + " = '" + oldLocation + "'"+ DATE +
                " = '" + newDate + " WHERE " + ID + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + DATE + " = '" + oldDate + "'"+ NOTATHOMES +
                " = '" + newNotAtHomes + " WHERE " + ID + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + NOTATHOMES + " = '" + oldNotAtHomes + "'";
        Log.d(TAG, "updating: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "updating: Setting map number, Location, Date and Not at homes to new values: Map number: " +
                newMapNo + " Location: " + newLocation + " Date: " +
                newDate + " Not at homes: " + newNotAtHomes);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public void deleteData(int id, String mapNo, String location, String date, String notAtHomes){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + ID + " + '" + id + "'" + " AND " + MAP_NO + " = '" + mapNo + "'" +
                LOCATION + " = '" + location + "'" + DATE + " = '" + date + "'" + NOTATHOMES +
                " = '" + notAtHomes + "'";
        Log.d(TAG, "deleting: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "deleting: Deleting note with values: Map number: " + mapNo + " Location: " + location + " Created on: " + date + " With notes: " + notAtHomes + ".");
        database.execSQL(query);
    }
}
```

MainActivity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.TheAbstractLightbulb.cohen.not_at_homes_app.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/BackgroundGrey">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="449dp"
        android:onClick="toInputScreen"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:text="@string/ButtonAddButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.733"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/MainListView"
        android:layout_width="336dp"
        android:layout_height="521dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:divider="@color/blackText"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

EditData XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".EditData"
    android:background="@color/BackgroundGrey">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton2"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:onClick="toSaveField"
        android:text="@string/saveButton"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.005"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:onClick="toDeleteNote"
        android:text="@string/ButtonDeleteButton"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:onClick="toSendNote"
        android:text="@string/sendButtonText"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textNotAtHomes2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@color/hintTextColour"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/hintText2"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hintTextColour2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:padding="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ListName2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/BackgroundGrey2"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/blackText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mapNoDisplay2"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/BackgroundGrey2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/blackText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.065" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dateDisplay2"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/BackgroundGrey2"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textColor="@color/blackText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.065" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If you are not comfortable with Sqlite, there's a library for you. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you are querying. These are all the exact same string

```
String map = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
String date = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
String notAtHomes = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
```

So therefore, sqlite can't find what you passed into `dbHelper.getItemID`, returns an invalid ID value.

I think you're looking to get different data from the adapter, which isn't really possible because you only added the third  column of the cursor to the adapter.

```
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        listData.add(data.getString(2));
    }
```

You should really consider using a CursorAdapter to correctly implement a ListView with a Database

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, as i said, i am new to java code and and not at all good at understanding SQLite and how it works. How are the string variables all the same thing? And what do you mean when you say that i have only added the third column of the cursor to the adaptor? Thanks for your patience. :-)

Comment: I mean exactly what I said... Try individually learning Java before Android, and general database theory before SQLite... Let's put it this way. `getItemAtPosition(i)`... The value of `i` never changed between those 4 lines of code. And `data.getString(2)` is the third column of the database... I don't know if you copied that code, or what, but you might want to try something smaller to get started with the basics

Comment: The reason i only have the third column in the `data.getString(2)` is because this returns the name of the item on the list view and I do not want the other database items to be displayed as the name. For example, if the third column is equal "Bob" and the fourth column is equal to "aged 24" and the fifth column is equal to "bob@example.com.au", I only want to display "Bob" as the name of the list item, but onItemClick I want to be able to retrieve the values of column 4 and 5 and display them on the next activity.

Comment: I do though see my mistake in the getItemAtPosition(i) area. i have remedied this problem.

Comment: You need a different adapter in order to store all the data, show only one item, and still able to extract the rest. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: That's one option. What I linked to is ArrayAdapter. You can use either, but CursorAdapter is more performant, if you care about that yet